# Windows Mobile - SystemState.PhoneMissedCall Problem

Tags: windows-mobile

I am using SystemState.PhoneIncomingCall to intercept missed calls. The problem is, if I have multiple missed calls, I get notification only for the first missed call and not for the rest. The rest of notifications are invoked when user views call history. How can I get notification for all missed calls at the time of actual incoming call? Also, I get duplication notification (first, at the time of missed call and other at the time of viewing history). How can I avoid multiple notification for same missed call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssmartdevicesvbcs/thread/bb8f1262-564c-4c0c-8d34-9a1150a7586f).